Something has corrupted nautilus so that nothing displays in Ubuntu 24.04
I was having some issues with my Ubuntu 24.04 VM where it wasn't booting, and if it did then it would crash if I did anything. After many restarts (some in recovery mode) the issue seemed to have fixed itself. I think VirtualBox may have reset something as I now get dialogue that I seemed to only get on the first boot of a VM?
Anyway that's not the thing I'm most worried about. When I try to launch the file manager GUI, nautilus it appears seemingly only as the sidebar menu, but is completely blank. The window has weird behavior, I can move it around but it leaves a trail of where its been.

Also when I was in VS code and tried to delete some files via the terminal, I got an error, so I clicked report and this really weird error window popped up.

I can access files via terminal, but any file GUI doesn't work.
I've tried reinstalling nautilus and updating a bunch of things, but nothing seems to work.
I just tried to commit a change in VSCode using the GUI, and this error message popped up.

